# Why emails are not sending on production server?

Tags: grails

I'm using the grails plugin "mail=0.9". Emails are not sending on production server. It just works fine on development environment on localhost.

Error is given below;

```
Stacktrace follows: 
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:319)
        at org.grails.mail.MailService.sendMail(MailService.groovy:63)
        at org.grails.mail.MailService.sendMail(MailService.groovy:46)
        at org.grails.mail.MailService$sendMail.call(Unknown Source)
        at MailGrailsPlugin$_configureSendMail_closure4.doCall(MailGrailsPlugin.groovy:86)
        at com.tkxel.chefvivant.api.SommelierController$_closure4.doCall(SommelierController.groovy:107)
        at com.tkxel.chefvivant.api.SommelierController$_closure4.doCall(SommelierController.groovy)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

Can anyone help me? Why emails are not sending?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally, after being spending the much time on this issue. I have fixed this error.

Actually the problem was just about to set the Gmail account settings. Google was sending the hidden captcha and that's obvious machine cannot recognize it. So that's why I was getting authentication error.

**Solution:**
I just unlocked the Gmail captcha and now it works fine.

```
Steps to reproduce this

1. Logout your gmail account first.
2. Visit this url https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha and then put username and password to login
3. Press "Continue" button to unlock the captcha
4. It will automatically save the settings.
```

Now, Check your application to hit the url like "Forgot Password" request. You will must receive email. :)

You can also read this article.
http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/uBdBQAuGeTw

Thanks

Comment: Oh my god man... Spent almost 2 hours on this issue but couldn't find any solution, you saved my day.. That worked like a charm.. Thankyou so much for this.. +1

Answer (score 0):

`javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException`
 means that you are useing incorrect credentials to access to account you use to send emails.

Comment: I checked my settings in Config.groovy and I can access the email address. 

grails {
    mail {
        host = "smtp.gmail.com"
        port = 465
        username = "xxxxx@gmail.com"
        password = "xxxx"
        props = ["mail.smtp.auth":"true",
                 "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port":"465",
                 "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class":"javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory",
                 "mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback":"false"]
    }
}

Comment: Try to add "mail.debug": "true" in props, this can be helpful

Comment: Mr.Cat

I really appreciate you for helping me. This line of code "mail.debug": "true" helped me alot to fix this issue. 


Thanks :)